# Binding behaviour differences between .net 3.5 -> 4.5

Tags: wpf, binding, converters, .net-4.5, behavior

Im upgrading some 3.5 code to 4.5 (VS 2012), and seem to get different behaviour in regard to how converters are executed. I've demonstarted the problem in an example below.

When compiling for .net 3.5, changing the value in the textbox results in just a "ConvertBack".

When compiling for .net 4.5, changing the value in the textbox results in both "ConvertBack" and "Convert".

I thought it might have something to do with "KeepTextBoxDisplaySynchronizedWithTextProperty", but setting it to false doesn't seem to help.

Other than fixing up the logic to support the new behaviour, is there another option?

```
public class ConverterTest : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Convert");
        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ConvertBack");
        return value;
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return this;
    }
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    double m_test = 5.678;
    public double Test
    {
        get { return m_test; }
        set { m_test = value; }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        FrameworkCompatibilityPreferences.KeepTextBoxDisplaySynchronizedWithTextProperty = false; 

        DataContext = this;

        var tb = new TextBox();
        tb.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, new Binding("Test")
        {
            Converter = new ConverterTest(),
                            Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay,
            UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged
        });
        Content = tb;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is all about Binding mode. As those differ in 3.5 and 4.5, try specifying `Mode="OneWayToSource"`

Comment: I've edited the example so that the binding is explicitly TwoWay (I need it to be TwoWay), ... but still produces the same behaviour